# C# - Filtering a DirectorySearcher for groupmembers

Tags: c#, winforms, filter, active-directory, directorysearcher

my issue is about filtering members of a specific group to be not shown in the userlist. 
So far to that, this is my code to filter them out so far:

```
searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(cn=*{0}*)(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!(adminCount=1))(!(cn=*Admin*)))",SuchfeldNachName.Text).Replace("**","*");
```

This is how I am trying to filter it right now. Obviously, I am trying to not show admins in the userlist. But thats not a fine solution for me, because in the final state, I want it to filter out four specific Active Directory groups.

These are the four groups I want to filter out:

- Domain Admins
- Enterprise Admins
- Policy Creator Owner
- Schema Admins

Now my question:

Is there a possible way to filter out the groupID's? So that the users in these groups are not shown in my userlist.

My idea was something like

```
(!(primaryGroupID= 512))
```

Second part of my question: Is there a list for all the group ID's?

Appreciate help in advance!

Comment: What if a user belongs to group MyGroup and MyGroup belongs to Domain Admins. This means that the user also belongs to Domain Admins group. Should the user also be filtered in this case?

Comment: Yes, every user belonging to one of these 4 groups

Comment: One way is to use LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN filter (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx). It may work slow on enterprise environments. The other way is to expand group membership recursively (including nested groups membership) and add this membership to the filter (be aware that filter has limited length) or retrieve all user then filter invalid ones one the client side.

Comment: Also good practice is to search Domain Admins and other standard users and group by SID due to internationalization. If it does matter, take a look at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978401.aspx

Comment: still didn't solve my problem so far. Im trying it with if (result.IsMemberOf("my4groups")) , but it doesn't work for me. Appreciate help

Comment: This method will not work for nested groups. It just checks if a user exists in a group's member attribute (https://forums.asp.net/t/1983494.aspx?LDAP+IsMemberOf+of+UserPrincipal+class+is+not+working+as+expected). However if a user was directly added to a group the method should work. If it does not, please post the code example. Also be aware that the performance of the method is terrible.