# Active Directory users import in MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to fetch all the users of particular group from Active Directory of LDAP server. Authentication becomes success but i am getting null in result.
Following is my code.

Domain-172.11.12.123
Email-sample@email.com
password-123456

```
 using (var context = new DirectoryEntry(user.Domain,  user.Email, user.Password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure))
            {

                try
                {                    
                    string FirstName;
                    string LastName;
                    string ADUserName;
                    string Email;

                    using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(context))
                    {
                        searcher.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(samaccountname='user3'))";
                        List<string> Adusers = new List<string>();
                        System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();




                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    TempData["message"] = "error";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "ADuserList");
                }

            }
```

What wrong is going on.
Thanks in advance

Comment: if you rdp to the dc and start the `dsa.msc` and go search - advanced  and paste your query, does it work? The syntax looks somewhat strange (you have two ands and no ors, afaic just one and would've sufficed)

Comment: Verify that your first argument in DirectoryEntry ctor is LDAP://172.11.12.123 Using filter samaccountname='user3' you perform search for the user "user3" in Active Directory. Verify that this user exists. Also single quotes are not required. Just type samaccountname=user3

Comment: thanks i will check, and can you please suggest me the correct format.

Comment: Do you also need to fetch nested group members? For example you would like to retrieve all users that belong to group A. And there is a group B that also belongs to group A. Group B has its own users. These users also belong to group A. If this is your case take a look at my comments at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932638/c-sharp-filtering-a-directorysearcher-for-groupmembers?noredirect=1#comment69146951_40932638

Comment: Thanks @oldovets for your reply, solution was helpful too and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace.

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context for the currently connected AD domain
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find the group in question
    GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

    // if found....
    if (group != null)
    {
       // iterate over members
       foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
       {
           Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.DisplayName);
           // do whatever you need to do to those members
       }
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Read more about it here:

- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

**Update:** in order to get all the users of a given OU, the approach is quite different.

You need to create a separate `PrincipalContext` that defines what OU you're interested in - then you need to use a `PrincipalSearcher` to get all the users from that OU:

```
// create your domain context and define what OU to use:
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null, "OU=YourOU,OU=SubOU,dc=YourCompany,dc=com"))
{
   // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for any UserPrincipal 
   UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

   // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
   PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

   // find all matches
   foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
   {
       // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
   }
}
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much. That worked like a charm. But it is not working when i am passing OU(Organisation unit) in group. What to do in OU case.

Comment: @C.jacking: well, an "OU" is not a group - so this will **NOT** work for an OU, of course..... what are you trying to do? List all users in an OU ? Or finding an OU in your AD tree? Or what else?

Comment: I want a list of all the users of a particular OU and Group both. Problem of group has been solved by your code but i want list according to OU too.

Comment: sir how to filter on this basis of OU